# Lines in $\mathbb{F}_3^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

Considering the vector space $\mathbb{F}_3^n$, I need to show that, given three vectors $u,v,w$, the set $\{u,v,w\}$ is an affine subspace if and only if $\forall i\in\{1,...,n\}:u_i+v_i+w_i=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I will refer to them as $v_0, v_1, v_2$ instead of $u, v, w$ for convenience). If they are an affine subspace, we may write
$$
v_i = a + i w
$$
for some $a, w \in \mathbb{F}_3^n$. In more detail, your space consists of at most three points, and thus must be $0$- or $1$-dimensional. So it fits on a line or $w=0$; either way the above holds.
Then
$$
v_0 + v_1 + v_2 = 3a + (0+1+2)w = 3(a + w) = 0.
$$
Conversely, suppose $v_0 + v_1 + v_2 = 0$. Let $a = v_0$ and $w = v_1 - v_0$. Then certainly $v_i = a + iw$ for $i = 0, 1$. Also,
$$
v_2 = -v_0 - v_1 = -2a -w = a+2w
$$
as desired.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm just unsure about one part, namely why you can write $v_i$ as $a+iw$.

Comment: @N.Wolf Your space is affine, so is a linear subspace plus a constant. Now there are at most three points in it (there may be duplicates in the list), so it is either 1 dimensional or 0 dimensional. Either way, it fits on a line (the 0 dimensional case is when w = 0)! I've updated the answer.